# Any VRM difference between Asus h610-m a and b660-m k?

Tags: motherboard, dvr-ms

Is it my imagination or will the VRM and performance under load will be the same with these 2 boards?

The components look the same to be, seems only the ports and ram sticks options are different?

2 boards are:

Asus h610-m k
Asus B660-m a

Will these 2 boards perform about the same?

[image]

Comment: Given that the boards are supposed to support all the same processors the power distribution is likely to be the same across all of their range. The main differences are going to be in peripherals such as memory, PCIe and other expansion slots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part the boards are very likely to perform the same.

Given that the boards are supposed to support all the same processors the power distribution is likely to be the same or similar across all of their range. The main differences are going to be in peripherals such as memory, PCIe and other expansion slots.

Looking at it though there are some differences in the area just above the CPU. There look to be 3 sets of regulators (obvious due to the 3 large black squares) and on the 610 the right hand one has two chips in the middle of that block while the left two only have one. On the 660 each block has two chips. Might be a sign that the 610 is not going to supply as much power and may throttle the power budget or not have quite as clean a power supply for the CPU. It may just be redundancy or they may not expect a 610 "budget" class board to get paired with an unlocked i9 that would draw more power.

I would expect it to work in pretty much all cases, but the 660 may perform better or allow the processor to boost higher due to having a cleaner power supplies.

Comment: Thanks, go the b660-k, performs great!